# Sed escaping from inside Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, sed

I have a Ruby script that calls 'sed' as so:

```
    command = "sed -i \"s*#{find_what]}*#{replace_with}*\" #{file} "
    system `#{command}`
```

When I have a replacement string that spans multiple lines it is not properly escaped and appears all on one line in the "file".

What can I do to escape the string properly so sed replaces it with the line breaks intact?

Thanks

Comment: What is the compelling reason for calling `sed(1)` from within Ruby? Ruby can do all that `sed(1)` can do, and then much much more. And is more portable.

Comment: Definitely - but the Ruby script sometimes interacts with files on remote systems via SSH. This way I can have one command that can be executed either on the local file system or sent as an SSH command.

Comment: Ah, so you're generating the command in one function and then executing it, potentially via `ssh`, in another function... alright. Well played. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your `replace_with` contains strings like this:

```
replace_with = "this should be\non two lines"
```

You'll need to escape the `\n` from the *Ruby* interpreter *and* the shell interpreter so that they can be read by `sed(1)`. Try this:

```
replace_with = "this should be \\\\non two lines"
```

The first doubling: `\\` to `\\\\` is to get all the backslashes past Ruby. The second doubling: `\` to `\\` is to get a backslash past the shell. `sed` ought to see only a single `\`.

A simple test:

```
$ cat command.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
command = "/bin/echo -e \"first line \\\\n second line\""

print `#{command}`
$ ./command.rb 
first line 
 second line
$
```

If you must use `sed` from within a script, please use the array-based execution method as suggested by [Ismael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571778/377270) and [pguardiario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8570937/377270). See the hilarious [Process Identifier Preservation Society website](http://bonedaddy.net/pabs3/log/2014/02/17/pid-preservation-society/) for detailed reasons why it is safer to avoid using the shell to start every new process. Better of course would just use the Ruby built-in support for replacement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. My replace_with string actually contains "\n" instead. I've been testing and the following seems to properly escape the newlines:
`command.gsub!(/\n/, '\\\n ')`

Comment: But how well will `sed` deal with `s/something with newlines/.../`?

Comment: @muis: I imagine poorly. But so far user1032752 has just mentioned the _replacement string_ has the newlines, which suits me fine.

Comment: I interpreted that as newlines in both parts but I guess I was wrong about that.

Comment: That is correct. Only the replacement string can have line breaks.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I'm trying to do this: `system("adb logcat -v time | sed -e 's/\\\\d*/TEST/g'")` it replaces the letter "d" with TEST instead of any digits. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also tried using `Shellwords`, no dice. Anything that uses a backslash like `\d` or `\w` will be stripped out

Answer (score 4):

```
script = "s*#{find_what}*#{replace_with}*"
system "sed", "-i", "-e", script, file
```

This way no escaping is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It might make more sense to break up the command into mulitple args, of which only the first [will get expanded](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)

```
exec '/bin/echo', '-e', 'first line \n second line'
```